# Styling DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC 3 view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have three DropDownLists in my view. The code I use to visualize them is this:

```
@{
    var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = String.Empty, Value = String.Empty });
    foreach (var name in ViewBag.Names)
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = name, Value = name });
    }
}
    <span>
        Repair Form : @Html.DropDownList("dropDownList", listItems)
    </span>
    //code...
    <span>
        Tools : @Html.DropDownList("kkcDropDownList", kkcItems)  
    </span>
    //code...
    <span>
        Document : @Html.DropDownList("docDropDownList", docItems)
    </span>
    //code...
```

And I get this as result :

[image: ComboAsItIs]

What I want to change is the order of appearance - now it's text-dropDown, text-dropDown..
Insted I want to be text and below the text the dropDown like this:

[image: ComboAsIWantIt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want the 3 groupings to align, I'd have two different suggestions.

If you want

```
text
dropdown

text
dropdown

text
dropdown
```

then you could simply add in the relevant `<br/>` tags after the text and after the dropdown code.

If you want

```
text       text       text
dropdown   dropdown   dropdown
```

then you'll need to add a css rule to give your spans a `display: inline-block;` and a relevant width to force the dropdown to wrap appropriately.

```
span
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

But, that will style all of your spans, so give your spans a class and then use that in the CSS definition.

```
<span class="aclass">
    Text: dropdown
</span>

span.aclass
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I need the second option. Is it possible to share a CSS example code?

Comment: I'll see if I can create an example for you

Comment: And here is an example without needing the extra <br/> markup. http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/KVzxu/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can put the label inside another element and define and assign a class to it, displaying it as a block.

**Option #1**

```
<span>
    <span class="list-label">Repair Form</span> : 
        @Html.DropDownList("dropDownList", listItems)
</span>
// css
span.list-label {
    display: block;
}
```

**Option #2**
Treat all labels as a block. If you use this with a textbox the label will be on top of the the input field.

```
<span>
    <label>Repair Form</label> : 
        @Html.DropDownList("dropDownList", listItems)
</span>
// css
label {
    display: block;
}
```